# hard surface pinching

Tags: modeling, topology

Im trying to model this piece of geometry but I keep getting some pinching.

[image]

[image]

This is the topo with subd turned off, as you can see theres a cluster of verts due to all the supported edges and bevels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your shape round, try this topology:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to maintain the crease that goes between the insets.

Comment: do you have a picture of the model object?

Comment: The first picture is what I’m trying to get except the pinching at the sides of each inset, sorry I’m at work. I’ll get a better picture later

Comment: is it what you're trying to achieve? https://zupimages.net/up/22/16/sglx.jpg

Comment: Yes that’s what I’m  going for!